# python exe program created using pyinstaller how do I profile the whole program using commandline -m cProfile

Tags: pyinstaller, cythonize, cprofile

usually i do python -m cProfile myapp.py  to run profiling.
i used pyinstaller my.spec --dist mydir --noconfirm
and created mydir/myapp an executable program
now i would like to run cProfile myapp and see the pstats.
how do I do that on this executable program?

Comment: you will have to program in a mechanism into the executable itself.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. How do I do that?